# different evaluation of pwd in ~/.bash_profile alias depending on type of quote

Tags: macos, shell, alias, osx-elcapitan

This is on OSX El Capitan, but also happens in my Ubuntu aliases as well.

I ran into an issue with an alias I created to pass the working directory to a docker container.

this wont work (always passes ~/Users/username for $(pwd) no matter what directory I'm in):

```
alias phpqa="docker run --rm -u $UID -v $(pwd):/app eko3alpha/docker-phpqa"
```

works:

```
alias phpqa='docker run --rm -u $UID -v $(pwd):/app eko3alpha/docker-phpqa'
```

However I started getting unexpected errors in my script when the wrong path was being passed in.  So I did an experiment.  I added both these aliases into my ~/.bash_profile.

```
alias getpath="echo $(pwd)"
alias getpath2='echo $(pwd)'
```

I logged off and then logged back in.

Change directory:

```
$ cd /Users/username/correct/path/to/project
```

Execute both aliases:

```
$ getpath
/Users/username

$ getpath2
/Users/username/correct/path/to/project
```

the alias with the double quotes always returns the users home directory while the alias with single quotes returns the current directory.  Can someone explain why that is?

Comment: searching is a useful knowledge. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: If single quotes were literal then why do I not get "echo $(pwd)" when I execute "getpath2" which is wrapped in single quotes.  Instead I get "/Users/username/correct/path/to/project"

Comment: It's easy, try yourself:

    echo "echo $(pwd)" aaaand
    echo 'echo $(pwd)'

Feel the difference?

Comment: Your answers are not addressing my issue as to why $(PWD) is being evaluated differently depending on single vs double quotes in my aliases

Comment: 1. its a comment, not answer 2. because this is POSIX, that's the reason. end of story. Ask the old men who wrote POSIX standards 30 years ago.

Comment: @IporSircer, not that long ago -- POSIX sh dates to the 90s. Though, granted, it was mostly influenced by ksh, which was mostly influenced by Bourne, so we can certainly trace the decisions at hand back to the 70s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alias definition is parsed like any other command. Inside double quotes, variable substitutions like `$UID` and command substitutions like `$(pwd)` are expanded. Inside single quotes, nothing is expanded: the only special character is a single quote which terminates the single-quoted literal.

> ```
> alias phpqa="docker run --rm -u $UID -v $(pwd):/app eko3alpha/docker-phpqa"
> ```

Assuming that your user ID is 1000 and the current directory is your home directory `/Users/username` at the time your `.bash_profile` is read, this defines the alias `phpqa` with the expansion `docker run --rm -u 1000 -v /Users/username:/app eko3alpha/docker-phpqa`.

> ```
> alias phpqa='docker run --rm -u $UID -v $(pwd):/app eko3alpha/docker-phpqa'
> ```

This defines the alias `phpqa` with the expansion `docker run --rm -u $UID -v $(pwd):/app eko3alpha/docker-phpqa`. Each time the alias is expanded, it's replaced by the corresponding string and that string is subject to the usual shell parsing rule. So each time the alias is used, the current value of the variable `UID` is used and the command `pwd` is executed.

The correct definition of this alias would be

```
alias phpqa='docker run --rm -u "$UID" -v "$PWD:/app" eko3alpha/docker-phpqa'
```

[Always use double quotes around variable and command substitutions unless you know that you need to omit them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). `$PWD` and `$(pwd)` are equivalent (the shell tracks the current directory in the variable `PWD`).

Alternatively, forget about quoting (except for double quotes around substitutions) and use a function.

```
phpqa () {
  docker run --rm -u "$UID" -v "$PWD:/app" eko3alpha/docker-phpqa "$@"
}
```

Comment: This would explain why I got my home directory vs working directory depending on the types of quotes.  Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: The function should have `"$@"` at the end to pass through extra arguments (as the alias does).

Comment: @Eko3alpha, ...btw, Gilles actually fixed a bunch of bugs in your alias when writing the function version -- it'll work correctly in directories that have spaces in your names, for instance; will explicitly pass an empty string through to `docker run` if `UUID` is undefined rather than running `-u -v` (thus giving a better error message); and is also more efficient since it doesn't bother spawning an unnecessary subshell to run `pwd`. You really should use the function.

Answer (score 1):

The `$(pwd)` gets evaluated when the alias is **created** if the alias uses double quotes:

```
$ alias getpath="echo $(pwd)"
$ alias getpath
alias getpath='echo /Users/username'
$ cd path/to/project
$ getpath
/Users/username
```

The `$(pwd)` gets evaluated when the alias is **used** if the alias uses single quotes:

```
$ alias getpath='echo $(pwd)'
$ alias getpath
alias getpath='echo $(pwd)'
$ cd path/to/project
$ getpath
/Users/username/path/to/project
```